# Error when instantiating a class which has an attribute with generic types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, generic-function

The following code is not completely in English but you'll get the point.

```
class Student : public Osoba{
    const int _brojIndeksa;
    Kolekcija<Predmet, int, 5> _polozeniPredmeti;
    vector<char*> _seminarski;      // naslovi seminarskih radova

    public:
    // constructor
    Student(char* ip, int brIndeksa) // brIndeksa is a global variable
        :Osoba(ip), _brojIndeksa(brIndeksa), _polozeniPredmeti()
    {
        cout << "Test!" << endl;
    }
```

The error I'm getting mentions `buffer being too small`.

I discovered that the issue lies in this line:

```
 Kolekcija<Predmet, int, 5> _polozeniPredmeti;
```

If I make it like this for example:

```
Kolekcija<int, int, 5> _polozeniPredmeti;
```

the program works. So this class `Predmeti` (school subjects) is somehow to blame:

```
class Predmet
{
    char* _naziv;
    char* _profesor;
    public:
    Predmet(char* naziv = "<naziv>", char* prof = "<prof>")
    {
        int size = strlen(naziv);
        _naziv = new char[size];
        strcpy_s(_naziv, size, naziv);

        size = strlen(prof);
        _profesor = new char[size];
            strcpy_s(_profesor, size, prof);
    }
```

I assume the default constructor of the above class is being called on `Student` instantiation.

Finally, the `Kolekcija` class looks like this (and it's been tested with built in types (int, double):

```
template<class T1, class T2, int max>
class Kolekcija
{
    T1* _clan1[max];
    T2* _clan2[max];
    int* _trenutnoClanova;
    public:

    Kolekcija()
    {
        cout << "pocetak" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            _clan1[i] = new T1;
            _clan2[i] = new T2;
        }
        _trenutnoClanova = new int(0);
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: I can't believe I missed adding `+ 1` because I've done so dozens of times this month and the rest of my code also contains it in such places.